# Text in the middle of div is it possible by a simple way?

Tags: css, reactjs

I try to put my text in the middle of my div but I don't found a nice solution and clean.
With padding the div growth, and it's not what I desire.
I can create a div box, but it's little tricky and when the code grows in complexity that's can add problem.
So if there is a simple solution, I want know it, like `TextAlign : "center"` but for the vertical, not only for the horizontal.

```js
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const style = {
    border: "1px solid black",
    // padding: "50px 0 0 0", // padding is not good
    // textAlign : "center"; // but for the vertical that's possible ?
    width: "100px",
    height: "100px"
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div style={style}>milieu</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

my try on code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-ellis-d9ju09?file=/src/App.js:0-366

result expected:

[image]

Comment: https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html#text under the "Centering vertically and horizontally in CSS level 3" heading

Comment: thx, I find this way to @WOUNDEDStevenJones ` const temp_box = {
  position: "relative",
  top: 0,
 };
 if(in_line === false) {
  temp_box["left"] = "50%";
 }
 
 const temp_cell = {
  position: "absolute",
  top: "50%",
  left: "50%",
  webkitTransform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
  transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
 };` with 2 nested div... because my problem is all the divs must be display in line for a menu.

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of flexbox to align an element vertically and horizontally center.

you can use this tool to learn flexbox - https://flexboxfroggy.com/

```
border: "1px solid black",
width: "100px",
height: "100px",
display: "flex",
alignItems: "center",
justifyContent: "center"
```

Comment: I know this method, but in my case that's don't work because I have a lot of successive div.

Comment: please share the code in codesandbox that you are trying to achieve.